# Debugging obfuscated code

Tags: c#, debugging, obfuscation

I have an application which is obfuscated with `EazFuscator.NET`. However, debugging this is quite impossible (even though it's a small application), for example, this is an error report:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Stacktrace:
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
at .(Object , RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs )
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnRunWorkerCompleted(RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.AsyncOperationCompleted(Object arg)
```

It clearly states the error is caused within a background worker. Since it's a small application, I have the feeling I know where but that's simply because it's a small application.

I'm already attaching the configuration files from the user and there's a checkbox to include a screenshot on the error report.

Is there any way to make this debugging easier for me while still having obfuscated code?

Comment: The whole point of obfuscation is to make deciphering the internal mechanism by removing debugging symbols, adding extra 'confusing' code, amongst other tactics (polymorphic self modifying code for example). If you don't have the debug symbols then you will just have to work it out for your self. For a decent look at the code though I recommend ILSpy which will reverse managed .net libraries and pretty format it for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of obfuscators generate mapping files that shows you mapping between original class / method names and obfuscated ones.
You should store these files somewhere for each version or ... and use them to find the real stack trace.

Comment: In many cases, no exception happened (so there is no stacktrace) but the software doesn't not work well on user's computer. And we cannot reproduce the issue. That's the key point.

Comment: Your answer should be accepted as the best answer. The situation in my comment above wasn't what OP had faced.

Comment: @zwcloud I've marked this as the answer now, as it's also true for Eazfuscator.NET (which the original question was about, 9 years ago).

Answer (score 3):

I had such experience of debugging client's issues on small obfuscated program too. And I can suggest you two options:

1) Making configurable verbose logging for your program, which client can enable in settings. You can collect huge amount of info using this logging (for example: entry point to each important method with parameters passed to it). Generally speaking having a good logging in your program is a HUGE time saver in debugging client's (and not only client's) issues.

2) Also if user will allow you to access environment you can reinstall application (or change specific DLLs) with unobfuscated ones temporarily. After debugging is completed - just revert changed DLLs back.

Comment: I went for the logging method. Each time the application starts it erases the log file, when it does crash for some reason it sends the logfile with the error report. This way you don't have big log files and I can debug it properly :-)

Comment: The user may cut off your access and make a copy of the unobfuscated dll.